V.Net.Salesman Unreachable Nodes at Intersections
I'm designing a network that has a layer of locations and a layer of street segments.  I need to design a route to connect these locations along the street segments using the shortest route possible.  I'm trying to use the v.net.salesman GRASS tool, but I'm running into an error code "0..ERROR: Destination node [cat 1] is unreachable from node [cat 265]".  I've tried multiple fixes such as fix geometries, topology checker, v.clean, but none of those seem to find any issues with my street segment layer.
On further inspection, it seems that this error pops up for any of my street segments that run into an intersection (see image below where I've highlighted one of the street segments that was said to have an unreachable node):

For sources: I've downloaded the 2023 Census TIGER Lines as my layer of street segments and is where v.net.salesman is running into issues.  Any insights on how to further debug this or should I be using a different plugin?

Have you tried snapping the points to the lines?

Yep!  I've tried both drawn shortest distance lines from the points to the street network, and also trying to run the tool after snapping the points to the lines, but it makes no difference.  Still get the same error when trying to run traveling salesman.
